# Date format in text and address block

Tags: datetime

In my generated letter I use `\formatdate{\MDay}{\MMonth}{\MYear}`. In header I specific `\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}`.

I have got then date like **10th May, 2012**, but I would like only **10th May 2012**. The same problem is in the address block, where is actual date generate automatically.

How can I check this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comma as a separator is actually hardcoded into the various definitions of `\formatdate`, but you may use the `etoolbox` package to remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\formatdate}{,}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following definition `\ddmmmyyyydate` to achieve (and reformat) what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ddmmmyyyydate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\formatdate}[3]{%
    \ifshowdow\shortdayofweekname{##1}{##2}{##3} \fi
    \@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
    \ordinaldate{\the\@day}\ \shortmonthname[\@month] \the\@year}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\today

\ddmmmyyyydate

\today
\end{document}
```

The `english` option to [`isodate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate) prints this output by default. Alternatively, use `\isospacebeforeyear` can be used to modify the separator between month and year:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate
\begin{document}
\today

\isospacebeforeyear{, }

\today
\end{document}
```